# Problemas con caracteres raros en PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un directorio telefónico pero al imprimir los nombres en el archivo HTML algunos nombres que tienen acentos me salen con caracteres raros con signos de interrogación.

Buscando me dicen que es la collación.
Mi única tabla está en collación: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Mi archivo de conexión es este:

```
//Realizamos la conexión a la base de datos
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $base);
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8",$conexion);
```

Mi archivo de principal es tiene los encabezados:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Pero nada no cambia nada, siguen apareciendo símbolos extraños como estos:

```
RÃ¡mirez Ã Ã“ Ã‰
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, la verdad soy nuevo en programación.

PD: Cuando hice mi directorio en mi entorno de pruebas todo funcionaba correctamente, al pasarlo a un servidor es donde comenzó el problemas con las comas.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto está mal escrito: `mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8",$conexion);` aunque desconozco si tiene que ver.  Comenta eso y prueba con  `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8mb4");`  Respecto a la collation, revisa no solo la tabla, sino sus campos, a ver si tambien tienen esa collation.

Comment: Cuando estes creado la base de datos en tu collación utf8mb4_spanish_ci, eso debe de corregir tu problema, es cuestion de probar.

Comment: Hola @masterguru muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, intente con tu código, pero aun sin éxito, en el caso de revisar los campos de la tabla no tengo manera de saber, pensaba que al hacerlo en toda la tabla con eso era suficiente.

Comment: Si tienes acceso al phpmyadmin para consultar la tabla, y te vas a la estructura, verás los campos de texto con su collation.  Si allí está bien es probable que ya tengas los datos corruptos de antes, quizás debido a una mala importación de los mismos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta.
El proyecto lo traje originalmente de PHPMyAdmin, donde no tenía problema alguno, el detalle fue cuando lo coloque en un servidor con Webmin, aquí tiene la misma versión de PHP, Apache y Mysql, el problema es con los datos, si no los guardo con acute; estos no se muestran con acento.

Comment: A ver, si ya has estado jugando con los datos, como decia, es posible que ya esten corruptos en la base de datos. Deja puesto el `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8mb4");` que te he dicho antes, e introduce nuevos datos con acentos y luego los muestras, y si salen bien entonces quiere decir que ya está arreglado, y que el problema ahora son los otros datos que ya tenia la base de datos **antes** de ese cambio, pues si fueron actualizados o insertados con una página de códigos distinta, no los vas a poder sacar bien y tendrás que reescribirlos de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta.
He realizado lo que me comentas, agregue un par de registros nuevos, el detalle es que continua mostrándome caracteres �? �?�? �? en algunos acentos.

Comment: ¿en algunos o en todos?  Te tienes que fijar solo en los que has agregado. Esos son los importantes ahora. El resto puede estar corrupto y no nos interesa ahora mismo. La pregunta es:  ¿en los nuevos registros, y solo en esos, siguen apareciendo mal los acentos?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Me fije en los 3 nuevos registros que hice y en todos me aparecían símbolos en los acentos.

Comment: vale, pues nada, ahora ya entrariamos en la configuración de tu servidor mysql. Por lo que sea se está columpiando y no nos hace caso con la línea `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8mb4");`. Revisa los archivos de configuración de tu servidor local y el nuevo, y mira si en el local tienes definidida alguna collation que no tengas en el nuevo. Normalmente está bajo la seccion [mysqld] de los archivos de configuración, que deberian estar por la carpeta /etc/mysql

Comment: y mi siguiente respuesta será tardia... me voy a dormir :-)  suerte!

Comment: Vale, como decia, localiza el archivo de configuración de mysql (por cierto, de que mysql hablamos? que versión? que motor?  mysql o mariadb?) y si es mariadb pon estas líneas bajo esa sección [mysqld]: `character-set-server  = utf8mb4` y `collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci`.. y si es mysql 8 entonces pon estas: `collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci` y `character-set-server = utf8`  (a mi me funcionan en un mariadb v10 y en un mysql v8)

Comment: Hola @masterguru gracias por tu respuesta y por toda la ayuda.
Por el momento la persona que me daba acceso a manipular el server salio por unos dias y no tengo manera de comprobar la configuracion que me comentas, en cuanto regrese vamos a intentar lo que me comentas y hacemos nuevamente la prueba para ver si con eso ya queda.
De antemano muchas gracias hermano por toda tu ayuda.